# Pagination in news script

Tags: php, pagination

I have a simple news system that i need to change so i can limit the items per page but i don't have anything that would do this, so i need to do this myself.

Basically the function just displays the whole array of the flat files and i would like to limit it to 3 items per page(configurable).

My starting logic was:

```
$itemspage=pages->current_page;
$itemsperpage=3;
$limitn=$itemperpage*$itemspage;
$itemindex=$limitn-2;
```

if page was 1 it would display the news from array index 1,2,3
if page was 2 it would display the news from array index 4,5,6
and so on...

i think this logically should work but what if the news in the array  can't be split into 3? with this logic this should (at least on the starting index) cause a bug.

The whole code is here:

```
$list = $this->getNewsList();
  $pages = new Paginator;
  echo "<table class='newsList'>";
  foreach ($list as $value) {
    $newsData = file($this->newsDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    $newsTitle  = $newsData[0];
     $submitDate = $newsData[1];    
     unset ($newsData['0']);
     unset ($newsData['1']);

     $newsContent = "";
     $itemspage=pages->current_page;
     $itemperpage=3;
     $limitn=$itemperpage*$itemspage;
     $itemindex=$limitn - 2;
     foreach ($newsData as $value) {
           $newsContent .= $value;
     }

    echo "<tr><th align='left'>$newsTitle</th>
              <th class='right'>$submitDate</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$newsContent."<br/></td></tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

The for hasn't been done yet only the logic behind the split. Could you help me?

Comment: Your script looks complicated. There's an excellent tutorial on PHP pagination at this channel: www.youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're building your $newsContent, but maybe your answer is in here:

```
$list = $this->getNewsList();

$pages = new Paginator;
$itemspage = $pages->current_page;
$itemperpage = 3; // you might want te define this property in the paginator also ($itemperpage = $pages->items_per_page);
$currentPageList = array_slice($list, ($itemspage - 1) * $itemperpage, $itemspage);

echo "<table class='newsList'>";
foreach ($currentPageList as $value) {
    $newsData = file($this->newsDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    $newsTitle  = $newsData[0];
    $submitDate = $newsData[1];
    unset ($newsData['0']);
    unset ($newsData['1']);

    $newsContent = "";
    $limitn=$itemperpage*$itemspage;
    $itemindex=$limitn - 2;
    foreach ($newsData as $value) {
        $newsContent .= $value;
    }

    echo "<tr><th align='left'>$newsTitle</th>
    <th class='right'>$submitDate</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>".$newsContent."<br/></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Notice the [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

> **array_slice()** returns the sequence of elements from the array array as specified by the offset and length parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code mate it helped me with the logic :)

By the way, one little adjustment: in the array slice callout the length parameter was $itemsperpage and not $itempage. Despite that this works beautifully!

Comment: I have another issue if you could help yet again in this, you would be a god :P.

I have the split done of the array and i'm trying to put the paginate direcly in the function so it will display directly on the site by calling the news system.

http://pastebin.com/XWCLFe7e   - this is the news system


This is where i call the function to display my news.(in a section of my main page.
`code`<div id="content">
         <?php $newsHandler->displayNews();<br/>
   
   ?>
   
    </div>`code`